# Angular Directive Compile function: replace is ignored, and compiled content is nested

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Directive:

```
app.directive('myCarousel', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        , transclude: false
        , replace: true
        , scope: true
        , compile: function compile($element, $attr) {

            var html = '<ul rn-carousel="" rn-carousel-indicator="">' + $element.html() + '</ul>'
            $element.html(html)

            return function ($scope) {
                $compile($element.contents())($scope);

            }
        }
    };
})
```

Usage:

```
<my-carousel>
        <li>Todd</li>
        <li>Andrej</li>
    </my-carousel>
```

Output

```
<my-carousel class="ng-scope">
    <div id="carousel-1" class="rn-carousel-container ng-scope" style="width: 1600px;">
        <div id="carousel-2" class="rn-carousel-container" style="width: 1600px;">
            <blah>
        </div>
    </div>
</my-carousel>
```

The problems I have (at least known problems

1 - I still have the my-carousel element, why didn't the replace remove it?  Do I need to do this myself because I am writing the compile function?  HOw would I go about that?

2 - for some reason it looks like the rn-carousel inner directive is getting compiled inside of itself?  This could very well be my lack of understanding on this inner directive on how it works.  But does  it look like anything is terribly wrong with this compile function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current working solution (albeit without replacing the parent element):

```
eido.directive('myCarousel', function ($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        , transclude: false
        , replace: true
        , scope: true
        , compile: function compile($element, $attr) {

            var html = '<ul rn-carousel="" rn-carousel-indicator="">' + $element.html() + '</ul>'
            $element.html(html)

            return function ($scope) {
            }
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the compile function, you are expected to do DOM manipulation by yourself.  You can achieve the same effect as `replace: true` using `replaceWith`:

```
compile: function($element, $attr) {
  var html = '<ul rn-carousel="" rn-carousel-indicator="">' + $element.html() + '</ul>'
  $element.replaceWith(html);

  return function(scope) {
    /*probably don't need to compile element contents here*/
  }
}
```

But... It doesn't look like you need to use compile at all.  By giving the directive a template, and using transclusion, you can accomplish the same thing:

```
app.directive('myCarousel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    template: '<ul rn-carousel="" rn-carousel-indicator="" ng-transclude></ul>'
  };
})
```

Comment: I thought I tried this combination unsuccessfully.  I will investigate again.  THank you

Comment: Did it work?  I'm curious to know if your situation requires something more complex.

Comment: Error 1: TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined

Comment: Error 2: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <ul rn-carousel="" rn-carousel-indicator="" ng-transclude="" class="ng-scope">

Comment: I had tried this earlier, and knew it didn't work.  I think error 2 is the root error while error 1 is caught first.

Comment: Change transclude=false to true?

Comment: Oops - you are correct.  Now I get just the first  error, "error 1"

Comment: Also when I switch $element.html() to $element.replaceWtih() it just displays the user list as opposed to compiling and rendering the contents.  .html() seems to engage the compile somehow.

Comment: Going back to the transclude problem, it is almost as though it may be compiling the template and rendering it PRIOR to the transclusion.  I would need the transclusion to happen as a first step - because the child elements are necessary for the rn-carousel directive (which may have some bugs in it, this is a 3rd party I snapped in for the time being, I haven't fully investigated its implementation).